# python - how to delete a row in DictReader

Tags: python-3.x

I am sometimes using Python for some automation stuff. I just came around a Problem I am not able to solve. 
I use Python 3.3.
I have a .csv file opened as a DictReader. Now I want, depending on a condition, to delete a row in the DictReader.

The code looks pretty much like:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ";")
...
if True:
    del reader[row]
```

Well, Python tells me that: "the dictReader object does not support item deletion".
Something there I am totally missing? Is there a built-in way to do it and I just did not find it in the manual, or do I have to use some kind of workaround?

best regards,
moritz

Comment: why do you want to delete the row? If you don't need the value, just disregard it. If you want to edit the csv file, you will need to write to a new file with csvWriter

Comment: I want to edit the Dictionary depending on some stuff and then give it to other functions. There are some lines in the Dictionary which hold the same information. But it's not linear, so sometimes its 3 times the same information, sometimes only 2, so its hard for me to find a criteria to disregard some of the rows.